# Compute $\int_{\Gamma}\omega$ where $\omega=(y-2z)dx+(x-z)dy+(2x-y)dz$

Tags: integration, parametrization

> Compute $\int_{\Gamma}\omega$ where $\omega=(y-2z)dx+(x-z)dy+(2x-y)dz$ and $\Gamma$ is the intersection between: $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2$ and $x-y+z=0$

My attempt:

$\Gamma$ is some kind of ellipse in the plane $x-y+z = 0$. Taking $z$ from the second equation and substituting in the first we get:

$$x^2+y^2+(x-y)^2=r^2$$

How do you continue from here with the parametrization? Is there a general approach to this kind of things?

Calculated it further and got: $\displaystyle x^2-xy+y^2=\frac {r^2}2$. How do I transform it in the form of a ellipse?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel That is true, still, how to make that in the form of an ellipse? Standard form: $(\frac xa)^2 + (\frac yb)^2 = r^2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\Gamma$ is the intersection between a sphere centred on the origin and a plane passing through the origin, thus a circle centred on the origin. The normal vector of this circle is $(1,-1,1)$, so find two *unit* vectors perpendicular to each other and to $(1,-1,1)$. One possible choice is $\frac{\sqrt2}2(1,1,0)$ and $\sqrt{\frac23}\left(-\frac12,\frac12,1\right)$.

The two new vectors are an orthonormal basis for the plane the circle lies in, so we can use the ordinary parametrisation of the circle, just with different basis vectors:
$$\sqrt{\frac23}\left(-\frac12,\frac12,1\right)r\cos t+\frac{\sqrt2}2\left(1,1,0\right)r\sin t$$
$$=r\left(-\frac{\sqrt2}{2\sqrt3}\cos t+\frac{\sqrt2}2\sin t,\frac{\sqrt2}{2\sqrt3}\cos t+\frac{\sqrt2}2\sin t,\sqrt{\frac23}\cos t\right)$$
Of course, $t$ runs from 0 to $2\pi$.

Comment: How did you get to those numbers?

Comment: @C.Cristi First notice that $(1,1,0)$ is orthogonal to $(1,-1,1)$ because the dot product is 0. Normalise $(1,1,0)$. Then take the cross product of the preceding two vectors and normalise that for the third vector.